# Can I create a signup and login system on GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, firebase, github, deployment

Is it possible to create a login and signup system on GitHub pages by linking Google firebase's database

I searched for this on the internet but no results.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So your question could use a lot more information to make it easier on how to answer. However, I assume you are asking if you can host a website that uses Google Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database on Github Pages and for that the answer is yes.

It's important to note that GitHub Pages only hosts static web pages, so any dynamic server-side functionality would need to be handled by Firebase or other backend services

I would recommend taking a look first and understanding the Firebase documentation specifically the [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) section. It is one of the most well documented and quite easy to pick up.

Anyway a basic example would look like this:

1. Set up a Firebase project: Go to the Firebase console and create a new project or use an existing one. Enable the Firebase Authentication service and configure the authentication providers you want to support (e.g., Google, Email/Password).
2. Create your website: Develop your website's frontend code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) that includes the login and signup forms. You can create separate HTML pages for login and signup or implement them within the same page.
3. Include Firebase SDK: In your HTML file, include the Firebase JavaScript SDK by adding the following script tag to the head section:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

4. Initialize Firebase: Initialize Firebase in your JavaScript code using your Firebase project's configuration. You can find the configuration details in the Firebase console under the project settings.

   ```
    // Initialize Firebase
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
      projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
      // ... other Firebase configuration properties
    };
   ```

   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
5. Implement the login and signup functionality: Use Firebase SDK methods to handle user authentication. You can use functions like `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` for signup and `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` for login. Firebase has multiple options for this choose the one you feel is most suitable.
6. Deploy your site to GitHub Pages: Commit and push your website's code to a GitHub repository. Enable GitHub Pages in your repository settings, and select the branch or folder where your site's code resides. Once enabled, your site will be accessible via the GitHub Pages URL.
7. Test the authentication flow: Open your site using the GitHub Pages URL and test the login and signup functionality. Users will be able to create accounts, log in, and authenticate using the configured Firebase authentication providers.

Hope this helps.